# Stored procedure to fetch entire row from database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I am a beginner to MYSQL and currently practicing stored procedures. I am trying to create a procedure that should fetch a row of an entire field when given an input parameter. Is there any workaround for this? If yes, then it would be an immense help.

Many Thanks

Comment: PL/SQL is related to Oracle, not MySQL; perhaps you'd want to remove that tag.

Comment: 'fetch a row of an entire field' - I have no idea what this means can you clarify by example please.

Comment: @P.Salmon Well what I'm trying to say is I want to create a procedure for a table where it should display only the selected row instead of whole table and that selected row should be my input parameters. Suppose the selected row contains student name, class and subjects as fields/columns and I would like to display data of a single student instead of all students. Hope this is clear

Comment: @Littlefoot Thanks for the suggestion, I removed it.

Comment: 'Hope this is clear' - it's not - 'that selected row should be my input parameters.' indicates you already have all the info you need..

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes but still somewhere there's some confusion on how can I do it

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Forum.

A stored procedure can simple consist of a SELECT statement that returns all the columns in the row you want. e.g.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `myproc`(IN `p_id` INT(11))
    READS SQL DATA 
    SELECT id, COL2, COL3, ETC
    FROM `mytable`
    WHERE id = 'p_id';
```

If you need to traverse a table, looking at every row that meets some criteria, then you need to DECLARE a "cursor", and use that to fetch the rows you want. Here is a template I use to create new procedures that need to traverse a table - it can be adapted to suit your needs. In this template I nly retrieve two columns from the cursor, but you can retrieve any number. You have to declare a local variable for each column in your SELECT so the FETCH statement has somewhere to put the data it retrieves from the cursor:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `traverse_table`()
        READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        DECLARE var_id INT(11) UNSIGNED;
        DECLARE var_data varchar(16383);
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE ecode varchar(1000) ;
        DECLARE emsg varchar(1000) ;
        DECLARE nextrecord CURSOR FOR   # here is the CURSOR DECLARATION
               SELECT `myid`,`mydata`     # It will return these rows, one
               FROM `mytable`           # at a time 
               WHERE `mydata` LIKE "ABC%";
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
        BEGIN
            GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 ecode = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, emsg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
            SELECT  var_id,var_data,ecode,emsg; 
        END;
        OPEN nextrecord;    
        FETCH nextrecord into var_id,var_data; # here is the first Fetch
        WHILE (done = FALSE) DO 
            # >>>>>> do something with var_id,var_data here <<<<<<
            SET done = FALSE;
            FETCH NEXT FROM records into var_id,var_data; # here is the second and subsequent Fetch
        END WHILE;
        CLOSE nextrecord;
    END
```